# How to use streaming twitter api to monitor an hashtag in java?

Tags: java, twitter-streaming-api

Can someone show me a java example? I was looking for it, but I haven't found nothing

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy, you must provide the hash tag in your `track` POST parameter:

The TwitterClient on github.com is a Java example of using the streaming API... it needs some work, most importantly the HttpURL needs changing to HttpsURL in TwitterClient.java:

```
/**
 * Extracts the host and post from the baseurl and constructs an
 * appropriate AuthScope for them for use with HttpClient.
 */
private AuthScope createAuthScope(String baseUrl) throws URIException {
    //HttpURL url = new HttpURL(baseUrl);
    HttpsURL url = new HttpsURL(baseUrl);
    return new AuthScope(url.getHost(), url.getPort());
}
```

and Change `http://stream.twitter.com/` to `https://stream.twitter.com/` in `example/Example.java`.

Get TwitterClient from `http://github.com/gistinc/TwitterClient` once you have it compiled run the example like this:

```
java <classpathstuff> example.Example username:password -t #YourHashTag
```

In CURL, make a file with this in called `track.txt`:

```
track=#YourHashTag
```

Then run curl like this... you can see it working:

```
curl https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json -uusername:password -d @track.txt
```

Hope this helps ;-)